# Pause video playing within <embed> Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, video, embed

I can only find the answer for an independent video tag and not for one which is embed in a HTML5 embed tag.

**This is my problem:** 
Using a AJAX file I'm getting an array of different type of files sources (mp4, pdf,xls,doc,etc) in order to populate my webpage. After retrieving my JSON array, I use the following line of code to populate:

```
 $("#modal-body").append('<div class="embed-responsive" style="padding-bottom:80%"><embed src="'+ $path +'" width="800px" height="500px" style="text-align:center;" /></div>');
```

Now, everytime I click on a file this is expanded to a modal window. In the case of a video, when the modal window appears,it automatically starts to play. I wish for when the user closes the modal window for the video to pause or stop.

However, when triggering a jquery .click() event which is closing a modal window, nothing happens.

```
$("#modalBtn").click(function(){
    $("#modal-window").toggleClass("invisible");// hide modal window

    $("video").each(function () { this.pause() });
});
```

I have noticed that this works if I am dealing with a single `<video></video>` but not for `<embed><video></video></embed>`

Can you help?

Comment: Been ages since I did, but I was able to accomplish this by programmatically clicking the pause button (element) vs. calling the pause function.  e.g. `$('button.pause', $('#modal-window')).click()`

Comment: You mean using within my $("#modalBtn").click(function(){}); or independent? Tried both aways, it still continues to play